# upload image using flask and ajx (alwys empty form data)

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, flask, flask-wtforms

i am new in Flask and try to upload images using ajax and form data and I always get form data sent as empty filed and my function always gets stuck in a validation error as filed is required even i click and send the image inside form,i need some one to help me to solve this issue.i see more solution  and dint got the issue.

my code here

```
@presentation.route('/presentation/updateImage',methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def updateImage() :

    UpdateImageForm = UpdateImage(request.form)
    if  UpdateImageForm.validate_on_submit() :
        
        image        = request.json.get("image")
        print(image)
        return jsonify({'status': "success", 'message': 'Password Changed Successfuly','id':image})               
    else:   
        errors = {}
        for field, field_errors in UpdateImageForm.errors.items():
            errors[field] = [str(error) for error in field_errors]
        return jsonify({'status': "errors ", 'message': errors})
```

my form is :

```
                    <div class="modal fade" id="update-img" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered1 modal-simple modal-add-new-cc">
                        <div class="modal-content p-3 p-md-5">
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                            <div class="text-center mb-4">
                              <h3 class="mb-2">Change Image</h3>
                           
                            </div>
                            <form id="updateImage"  method="POST" class="row g-3" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {{UpdateImageForm.hidden_tag()}}
                              <label class="form-label" for="bs-validation-upload-file">Presntaion  Images</label>
                              <div class="mb-3">
                                {{ UpdateImageForm.image(class_="form-control") }}<br>

                              </div>

               
                            
                              <div class="col-12 text-center">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-sm-3 me-1">Submit</button>
                                <button
                                  type="reset"
                                  class="btn btn-label-secondary btn-reset"
                                  data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                                  aria-label="Close">
                                  Cancel
                                </button>
                              </div>
                            </form>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

js code :

```
  // start edit image
  $(".table_for_data").on( 'click', '.editImage', function () {
    $("#updateImageResult").html("");
    // get id for update
    var myId = $(this).attr("data-id");
   // alert(myId)
    $("#updateImage").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault()
    var form_data = new FormData($('#updateImage')[0]);
        $.ajax({
          url: "{{ url_for('presentation.updateImage') }} ",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(form_data),                
            contentType: 'application/json',                 
            beforeSend:function(){
                $(".loadingImage").show();
            },
            statusCode: {
                404: function() {
                    alert( "page not found" );
                },
            },
            success:function(valdata) {
              alert('success')
             
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you should decide whether you want to send form data or JSON. If you want to send files, the former is recommended. A combination of both fails.

The following example shows you how to send the entire form to the server via AJAX.
On the server side, the form is initialized without `request.form` because files are not contained within this dictionary.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    abort, 
    render_template 
)
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileAllowed, FileRequired

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'Your secret here!' 

class UpdateImageForm(FlaskForm):
    image = FileField(validators=[
        FileRequired(), 
        FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'], 'Images only!')
    ])

@app.route('/update')
def index():
    form = UpdateImageForm()
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())

@app.post('/update')
def update():
    form = UpdateImageForm()
    if form.validate():
        print(form.image.data)
        return '', 200
    abort(400)
```

Please note that the content type is not set and the data is not processed. Only then will the form be sent in the "multipart/form-data" format, as required to upload a file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="my-form">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ form.image() }}
        <button type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>

    <script 
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" 
        integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        (function() {

            $('form[name="my-form"]').submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: {{ url_for('update') | tojson }}, 
                    type: 'POST', 
                    data: new FormData(this), 
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                }).done(() => {
                    console.log('Image uploaded successfully.');
                })
            });

        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```